# Blood sampling at home

Tags: hematology, mrna

I want to collect small blood samples at regular intervals (e.g. every 8 hours or more often) over a longer period (weeks to months). To avoid having to go to a lab or doctor to have this done, I want to do it at home. I will need to extract mRNA from PBMC from the samples.

Assume a test tube in which you have a piece of filtration paper. You prick your finger and let a couple of drops of blood soak into the filtration paper, and then seal the sample in the tube, and immediately place it in your regular freezer.

How long will the mRNA survive under these conditions?

Will it be better just to let the sample dry out inside the tube (e.g. using a desscant), or store it at room temperature?

Will it be possible to store it for e.g. a week before sending the batch in for analysis?